# vuejs how to increase a value inside the v-for

Tags: svg, vuejs2

I'm tiring to render a svg line graph using vue.js
This is my code.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">

    <div v-for="(scorex,key) in score">
        <p>{{x += 50}}</p>
    </div>
    <svg height="500" width="500" style="background-color:silver;">

<line v-for="(marks,key) in score" :x1="x+50" :y1="marks" :x2="x2+50":y2="score[key]" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5" />


</svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      score: [250, 225, 500, 175],
      x: 0,
      x2: 50
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

For the parameters **x and x1** I need to pass the value 50 initially and need to increment it by 50 until the loop finished.

What I did was I initialed x and x2 in the data object and try to increment it in the v-for statement. But It didn't work.

Comment: You can put *<line>* in custom component and pass *marks* as props, then write a computed property on marks and set new value of *x* and *x2*

Answer (score 0):

As I have taken in you want to get for line **x1**: x, x+50, x+100...,
**x2**: x2, x2+50, x2+100...
We can use index for this

> v-for also supports an optional second argument for the index of the current item.

Your code will be

```
<line v-for="(marks, index) in score" 
  :x1="x+index*50" 
  :y1="marks" 
  :x2="x2+index*50"
  :y2="marks" 
  style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5" />
```